# Swift: difference as String? vs. as? String

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a difference between `as? String` vs. `as String?` in Swift? If so, what's the difference and when should I use one vs. another?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's a subtle but important difference:

- `variable as? String`: `variable` can be any type, such as an array, an integer, etc. Cast to string if it's a string, set to `nil` otherwise.
- `variable as String?`: `variable` is a `String?`, but stored in an opaque type, such as `AnyObject?`, or it's a non optional string. If it's something different, a runtime exception is generated.

Some examples:

```
var x: AnyObject? = "Test"

x as String? // OK, the result is an optional string
x as? String // OK, evaluates to an optional string
"string" as String? // OK, evaluates to optional string

x as? Int // OK, evaluates to nil, it's not an Int
x as Int? // Runtime exception, it's not castable to optional Int
```

So:

- `as? Type` means: cast to this type, if possible, otherwise evaluate to `nil`
- `as Type?` means: cast to an optional `Type`, because I know it's an optional `Type`. I understand that if it's not that, a runtime exception is generated

However, the real difference is between `as?` and `as`: the former is an attempt to cast, the latter is a forced cast, resulting in runtime error if not possible.

**Update Dec 14, 2015** Since **Swift 1.2**, there are 3 variations of the `as` operator:

- `as?` is an attempt to cast, evaluating to `nil` if cast fails
- `as!` is a forced cast, resulting to an runtime exception if cast fails (this is what `as` previously did)
- `as` is now a special type of cast to be used when casting to equivalent types, usually bridged types, such as Swift's `String` and `NSString`.

Comment: Interesting answer, a small clarification if I may, given the above, what then is the difference between 'as' and 'as!' - both are forced casts that will generate runtime exceptions if casting invalid objects no?

Comment: @Woodstock the `as` operator has changed since 1.2. I've updated the answer. Thanks!!

Comment: thanks for the update my friend!

Answer (score 5):

From `The Swift Programming Language` book,

1. `as` is a *type cast operator* which we use to downcast to the `subclass` and `as?` is used for an optional form, when we are not sure if the `downcast` will succeed. Consider the following example

   ```
   for item in library {
         if let movie = item as? Movie {
            println("Movie: '(movie.name)', dir. (movie.director)")
         } else if let song = item as? Song {
            println("Song: '(song.name)', by (song.artist)")
         }
   }
   ```

The example starts by trying to `downcast` the current item as a `Movie`. Because `item` is a `MediaItem` instance, it’s possible that it might be a `Movie`; equally, it’s also possible that it might be a `Song`, or even just a base MediaItem.

2. `String?` An `optional value` either contains a value or contains `nil` to indicate that the value is missing.

From this,

1. `as? String` means when you don't know what you're downcasting, you are assuming that as a `String`, but it might me `Integer` or `Float` or `Array` or `Dictionary`
2. `as String?` means it's an `Optional Value`, it may either contain a `String` or `Nil` value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference.

In the first case, you are doing an optional cast to the type `String`. This will return a value if the object you are attempting to cast is indeed a `String` or nil if it is not.

In the second case, you are doing a forced cast to the type `String?`. If the value you are casting is not a string, it will crash your program.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**, there is diffrence.

`variable as String?` downcast to optional String.If `variable` is not `String?` it will cause run-time exception.

while `variable as? String` will return `nil` if your `variable` is not `String` type or return downcast `variable` to String. This is  **conditional downcasting**, if you not sure about down-casting you need to use this .